# OCaml dune: get absolute path to source directory

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

I have a project and there is a `./tests` directory at its root containing several hundred MB of data that is used by the tests of several libraries:

```
./tests
./src/lib1/dune
./src/lib1/tests/dune
./src/lib1/tests/tests.ml
./src/lib2/dune
./src/lib2/tests/dune
./src/lib2/tests/tests.ml
...
```

I also defined tests that use the data in `./tests` for each library like this:

```
(rule
 (alias runtest)
 (action (run ./tests/tests.exe)))
```

I now have to somehow communicate the location of the test data to each of my `tests.exe`. What is the most elegant way of doing this using dune?

It seems that dune copies my test data into `_build` which is unnecessary because the data never changes and it doesn't make sense to waste several hundred MB of space that way. From the documentation it seems that `%{project_root}` would contain the path to my source files but unfortunately, the variable evaluates to `.` which is useless for the tests which are run after a `cd _build/default/src/libX` and thus `.` does not point to the project root anymore. So is there a dune-way to specify the path to the original source directory without ugly hacks?

Right now, I'm using an environment variable containing the full path before I run `dune runtest` but is there a more integrated way?

Comment: This seems relevant: https://github.com/ocaml/dune/issues/2856

Comment: I would have thought that an environment variable would be set by dune to give you that info, but doing `Sys.command "env"` seems to indicate that no :/

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it  myself but it sounds like the `data_only_dirs` stanza is what you are looking for: https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dune-files.html#data-only-dirs-since-1-6

Comment: But how will my scripts know where the data directory is located? I somehow have to pass that information to them when dune runs them.